# Eclipse e4 program will not start

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I hava an Eclipse E4 application. I want to have a runnable exe file. The export of the exe file don't got any errors. But when I start the exported application the program doesn't start and give those errors:

```
!SESSION 2016-08-29 08:55:19.759 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_102
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY CR-IT_client 4 0 2016-08-29 08:55:20.930
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: CR-IT_client [26]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher; bundle-version="1.3.100"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2016-08-29 08:55:21.309
!MESSAGE Product CR-IT_client.product could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64 2 0 2016-08-29 08:55:21.653
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64 [40]
  Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher; bundle-version="[1.0.0,1.4.0)"


!ENTRY CR-IT_client 2 0 2016-08-29 08:55:21.653
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: CR-IT_client [26]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher; bundle-version="1.3.100"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-08-29 08:55:21.654
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI$URIPool$PlatformAccessUnit.setValue(URI.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI$URIPool.intern(URI.java:1949)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.createPlatformPluginURI(URI.java:2718)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.determineApplicationModelURI(E4Application.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

In Eclipse IDE it can run, but when I export it I got an error.
Someone that can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher` plug-in is missing from the build (or  possibly it is present but has the wrong version).

The configuration of plug-ins included in the RCP is separate from the configuration for the plug-ins used when you test your RCP from within Eclipse.

If you are using a '.product' file for the RCP go to the 'Contents' tab in the .product file editor and click the 'Add Required' button to add all the required plugins to the product. For a normal RCP there should be something like 100+ plugins in the contents list. Then rebuild the RCP.

In the above I am assuming you are using a 'plug-ins based' product configuration.